# MVVM Datagrid Binding SelectedItem not updating

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, datagrid

I'm new to WPF and MVVM and i've an applicaton that uses Entity Framework to connect to database and a datagrid to show the users of the application.

The users CRUD operations are made in a separate window and not in the datagrid.

My problems are related with the update of datagrid. 
The insert operation is ok but the update is not.

**View 1 (Users List):**

```cs
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Users, Mode=TwoWay}" 
  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay}" 
  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
  CanUserAddRows="False">
</DataGrid>
```

**ViewModel :**

```cs
class UserListViewModel: NotificationClass
{
    UserDBContext _db = null;

    public UserListViewModel()
    {
        _db = new UserDBContext();

        Users = new ObservableCollection<User>(_db.User.ToList());
        SelectedUser = Users.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<User> _users;
    public ObservableCollection<User> Users
    {
        get { return _users; }
        set
        {
            _users = value;
            OnProprtyChanged();
        }
    }

    private User _selectedUser;
    public User SelectedUser
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedUser;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedUser = value;
            OnProprtyChanged();
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand Edit
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(EditUser, true);
        }
    }

    private void EditUser()
    {
        try
        {
            UserView view = new UserView();                
            view.DataContext = SelectedUser;
            view.ShowDialog();

            if (view.DialogResult.HasValue && view.DialogResult.Value)
            {                    
                if (SelectedUser.Id > 0){
                    User updatedUser = _db.User.First(p => p.Id == SelectedUser.Id);

                    updatedUser.Username = SelectedUser.Username; //this doesn't do nothing, object is already with the new username ?!
                }
                _db.SaveChanges();              
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }   
}
```

after **_db.SaveChanges()**, datagrid should not be updated ?

**Model:**

```cs
class UserDBContext: DbContext
{
    public UserDBContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
}
```

**View 2 (User detail)**

```cs
public partial class UserView : Window
{
    public UserView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        DialogResult = true;
    }

}
```

**User object**

```cs
class User: NotificationClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; } 

}
```

**NotificationClass**

```cs
public class NotificationClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    public void OnProprtyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

if i close and open view 1, the new username is updated..

could someone help ? thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate on the commented line? Is this your main question?

Comment: no, that's another question. my main question is why datagrid is not updating. btw, the context is being auto updated, is that normal ?

Comment: You wrote that all changes to a `User` object are made in a separate window. Does `User` implement change notification ([`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2)) so that your `DataGrid` gets notified when something changes and updates himself?

Comment: yes it does, i edited the main post to include User object and NotificationClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` isn't enough, you have to explicitly invoke `PropertyChanged` (or in your case `OnPropertyChanged`) when a property changed.
See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification

You can do it like so

```
class User : NotificationClass
{
    private int _id;
    private string _username;
    private string _createdBy;
    private DateTime? _createdOn;

    public int Id
    {
        get => _id;
        set
        {
            if (value == _id) return;
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Username
    {
        get => _username;
        set
        {
            if (value == _username) return;
            _username = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string CreatedBy
    {
        get => _createdBy;
        set
        {
            if (value == _createdBy) return;
            _createdBy = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DateTime? CreatedOn
    {
        get => _createdOn;
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_createdOn)) return;
            _createdOn = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked ! many thanks @nosale !

what about the change made to SelectedUser being reflected in my context ?

if i do this :

```
SelectedUser.Username = "test";
User updatedUser = _db.User.First(p => p.Id == SelectedUser.Id);
```

i was thinking that SelectedUser object has the "test" username and updatedUser has the old username, but not .. updatedUser already have "test"

Comment: If another question came up ,especially when not related to your initial question, better ask/create a new question. And never ever use the answer section for that.